# Symfony2 Login via social network

Tags: facebook, authentication, symfony, social-media

I tried to login with social network in my website(online).I started with connect via facebook but I got this error

> :"URL bloquée: La redirection a échoué car l’URI redirigée n’est pas approuvée dans les réglages Client OAuth de l’application. Assurez-vous que le Client et l’identification Web OAuth sont activés et ajoutez les domaines de toutes vos applications dans la liste des URI autorisées."

I have this url " https://www.facebook.com/v2.3/dialog/oauth?response_type=code&client_id=130481527628156&scope=email&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2FArtisana%2Fweb%2Fapp_dev.php%2Floginsocial%2Fservice%2Ffacebook&display=popup"

The problem is the url is for the local website. when i change the url to the url of my online website it works for me.I don't kow how it take the url of local website.

Comment: I have this error now "ServiceNotFoundException in CheckExceptionOnInvalidReferenceBehaviorPass.php line 58: The service "hwi_oauth.security.oauth_utils" has a dependency on a non-existent service "hwi_oauth.resource_ownermap.main"."

Answer (score 0):

When you configure an oauth provider you have to authorized some callbacks urls. You should configure your development and prod callbacks urls

- http://localhost/loginsocial/service/facebook
- https://yourprodsite/loginsocial/service/facebook

You should find this configuration on the provider website (ie facebook)

[Check this documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login)

This secure that the provider return oauth informations to your website and not to another one